# How to swap keys in Vim normal mode, not just remap them?

Tags: vim, key-bindings

I use Dvorak, so I have the following in my .vimrc:

```
no t j
no n k
no s l
no l n
no j t
no k s
```

which maps the directional keys to back to the right side of the home row.

This usually works quite well, except in plugins.  For example, I can't navigate using up and down in the NERDTree plugin because it makes t something else.

Is there a way for me to, instead of simply remapping keys, tell Vim to consider a press of t in normal mode to be translated into a press of j, no matter what the context or plugin?

I seem to vaguely remember a vim command to alias one key to another, but I can't find it.

Comment: There are some nice caveats and comments to doing that discussed here: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_Vim_with_the_Dvorak_keyboard_layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found what I'm looking for:

```
set langmap=tj,nk,sl,ln,jt,ks
```

Comment: You've unmapped 't'?  Should there be a `jt` in there instead of one of the `tj`s?

Comment: Hey dvcolgan, what about for maps that involve `<c-*>`, so for example, if you press `ctrl+t` does it behave as `<c-j>`? That doesn't work for me. Have you run into this problem?

Answer (score 2):

It may be worth simply learning the Dvorak locations for the keys.  hjkl move, but (imho) not in a way that prevents their efficient use.  h and l are index and pinky on your right hand, j and k are middle and index on your left.

It takes a while to remap your brain, but much of the Vi keyboard layout is mnemonic so it is easier than it could be (e.g. with emacs which is pretty Dvorak hostile IMHO).